# How to store the location of top left corner of a selection box

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to store the upper left corner of the selected cell(s).  Later the code below selects a lot of different areas and, after executing it, I want to make the selected cell the top left corner of the originally selected cell(s).

I get an error at the line after `With Selection`:

```
Private Sub Test()

    Dim InsertPoint As Range

    With Selection
        Set InsertPoint = Range(.Row, .Column)
        'insert a bunch of code working with this selection
    End With
    'insert a whole wack of code selecting various things
    InsertPoint.select
End Sub
```

Can someone point me in the right direction/correct my coding please?

Comment: `Set InsertPoint = .cells(1)`

Comment: DANG!!!! I find if annoying how sometimes Cells works and other times Range works and it feels like you are doing the same thing.  Thought technically speaking if I use Cells(1), I get sent back to cell A1, but Cells(.row,.column) take me back to the upper left corner of what I had selected.  If you edit your answer I will mark it as accepted...NVM I cant accept a comment 8(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you are inside the [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx), everything prefaced with a period (aka `.` or *full stop*) will be in direct relation to the `Selection` that the With... end With block references.

```
With Selection
    Set InsertPoint = .Cells(1)
    debug.print InsertPoint.address(0, 0)
    'do lots of stuff here
End With

debug.print InsertPoint.address(0, 0)
```

So `Cells(1)` or `Cells(1, 1)` will still refer to the worksheet's A1 but inside that block `.Cells(1)` refers to the cell in the top-left corner of the Selection.

Comment: OK, I totally buy what you are saying, and it makes sense.  however when I run that small little chunk of code with .cells(1) and then do the InsertPoint.select after the "end with" , it takes me to cell A1.  I just re ran it to make sure, and it is still doing it.  However when I change the 1 to .row,.column, when I do the InsertPoint.select, I get the top left corner of what was selected.  I am guessing that this is based on the InsertPoint.select being outside/after the End With.

Comment: No that's not it. Once InsertPoint is set it should stay that way. There must be some anomaly generated by your code. I've tried it and it works. See what address(es) is spit back to the Immediate window with the above modifications.

Comment: figured it out.  Typo did me over.  I had retype my code instead of cut and paste and I typed set InsertPoint = Cells(1).  I missed the damned period before Cells.  Your code sir does absolutely what you said it would do.  Thank you very much for taking the time to help me with this.  Note to self, .cells is relative address and cells is absolute address.